# remover mascara para salvar no banco de dados

Tags: c#, banco-de-dados, asp.net-mvc-5, mask

estou usando o MaskMoney para criar uma mascara no campo para o usuário digitar. queria remover a mascara, salvando apenas os números e a virgula (2 casas decimais) no banco.

> R$ 1.300.000,00

salvando apenas

> 1300000,00

Estou usando asp.net-mvc, segue o controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "PessoaID,Nome,Telefone,Celular,Whatsapp,Email,CPF,Tipo,RG,CTPS,DataNascimento,DataAdmissao,DataDemissao,Senha,CargoID")] Funcionario funcionario)
    {
        //salario = Convert.ToString(salario);
        salario = Regex.Replace(salario, "[^0-9,]", "");

        funcionario.Salario = Convert.ToDecimal(salario);
        funcionario.tipo = 1;
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Pessoas.Add(funcionario);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        ViewBag.CargoID = new SelectList(db.Cargos, "CargoID", "Descricao", funcionario.CargoID);
        return View(funcionario);
    }
```

Create:

```
@model SAQ.Models.Funcionario

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<div class="form-horizontal">
    <h4 onmouseover="tooltip.pop(this, 'Este é meu texto na tooltip.')">Funcionario</h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Nome, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Nome, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Nome, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Telefone, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Telefone, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control telefone" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Telefone, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Celular, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Celular, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control celular", id = "txt-tel" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Celular, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Whatsapp, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2", id = "bt-copiar", title = "Clique em mim para copiar o Celular" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Whatsapp, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control celular", id = "txt-wpp", title = "Clique no Texto WhatsApp ao lado para copiar o Celular" } })
            @*<div class="btn" id="bt-copiar">Copiar</div>*@
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Whatsapp, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Email, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Email, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Email, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CPF, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CPF, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control cpf" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CPF, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    @*<div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.tipo, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.tipo, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.tipo, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>*@

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.RG, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.RG, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control rg" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.RG, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CTPS, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CTPS, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CTPS, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DataNascimento, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DataNascimento, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control data" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DataNascimento, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DataAdmissao, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DataAdmissao, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control data" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DataAdmissao, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Salario, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Salario, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control " } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Salario, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Senha, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Senha, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", id="Senha"} })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Senha, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>


    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CargoID, "Cargo", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownList("CargoID", null, "Selecione", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CargoID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Salvar" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $(".telefone").inputmask("mask", { "mask": "(99)9999-9999" });
            $(".celular").inputmask("mask", { "mask": "(99)99999-9999" });
            $(".cpf").inputmask("mask", { "mask": "999.999.999-99" }, { reverse: true });
            $(".data").inputmask("mask", { "mask": "99/99/9999" });
            $(".rg").inputmask("mask", { "mask": "99.999.999-9" });
            $(".dinheiro").maskMoney({ prefix: 'R$ ', allowNegative: true, thousands: '.', decimal: ',', affixesStay: true });
        });
</script>
<script> //copia os caracteres do telefone
    $('#bt-copiar').on('click', function () {
        $('#txt-wpp').val($('#txt-tel').val());
    });
</script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function (e) {
            $('#Senha').on('focus', function () {
                $(this).attr('type', 'text');
            }).on('blur', function () {
                $(this).attr('type', 'password');
            });
        });
    </script>

}
```

classe (só estou colocando o atributo que me da problema):

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:c}")]
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Preencha o Salário")]
[DisplayName("Salário")]
public decimal Salario { get; set; }
```

Comment: Use variavel = variavel.Replace('',", string.Empty);

Comment: Você vai salvar como string mesmo? Ou seu banco aceita "," como separador decimal?

Comment: @Sorack o salário está como decimal no Banco

Comment: Seu banco aceita decimal com vírgula?

Comment: Se você quiser tratar no JS você pode usar `.maskMoney('unmasked')` para obter o valor real. Ou no C# você pode fazer um replace `valor = Regex.Replace(valor, @"[^0-9,]", "");`

Comment: @Bacco campo `money` do SQL Server caso você coloque a linguagem em português é um dos exemplos

Comment: Normalmente o money remove os símbolos da língua neste caso.

Comment: Os tipos de dado `money` não são aconselhados. O ideal para armazenar valores monetários é o `decimal` mesmo. Tipos de dados `money` apresentam problemas em aplicações grandes e em transações de banco de dados. Há registro de perdas de dados e de baixa precisão em cálculos com o tipo de dados `money`.

Comment: Bom eu faço assim, configuro o `Globalization` para `pt-BR` e configuro os campos dinheiro (`money` ou `decimal`)  `$(".dinheiro").maskMoney({ prefix: '', allowNegative: true, thousands: '', decimal: ','});` dessa forma não precisa fazer mais nada, mas, é o jeito que eu utilizo.

Comment: Está correto em termos, mas você precisa garantir a integridade de seu banco de dados, desta forma, as funções `get` e `set` devem ser utilizadas no C# para que a validação dos dados não dependam só do cliente, porque não existe segurança do lado cliente. O OP tem que usar o setter e implementar as funções do próprio C# como `var Salario = string.Join("", Salario.Where(char.IsDigit))/100;`.

Comment: @VirgilioNovic sua alternativa seria algo que funcionaria para salvar as informações, porém a mascara não ficaria do jeito que o cliente quer...

Comment: @FabioSouza eu imaginei que isso é coisa de cliente, complicado !!! como eu disse é o jeito que eu sigo achei que não era nem legal colocar uma resposta... Acredito que você deve fazer isso no controller, então.

Comment: @VirgilioNovic eu tentei fazer pelo controller usando o Regex.Replace porém como a classe está configurada como decimal, ele nem envia o dado para o controller

Comment: coloque um campo a mais no seu método do controller mais ou menos assim: `public ActionResult Store(string Salario, Funcion ... )` depois você trabalha a informação e altera a variavel da classe responsável pelo Salário em decimal

Comment: @VirgilioNovic funcionou o que disse.. postei a resposta de como resolvi. Obrigado

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Resolvi meu problema assim:

```
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "PessoaID,Nome,Telefone,Celular,Whatsapp,Email,CPF,Tipo,RG,CTPS,DataNascimento,DataAdmissao,DataDemissao,Senha,CargoID")] Funcionario funcionario, string salario)
{
        salario = Regex.Replace(salario, "[^0-9,]", "");
        funcionario.Salario = Convert.ToDecimal(salario);
}
```

ou seja, inclui uma string salario, e tratei com Regex.Replace então salvou normalmente.

Comment: Marca como resposta, yo.

Comment: Não entendi o que quis dizer

Comment: É que você conseguiu resolver seu problema com o código que você postou, então, para não ficar como uma pergunta não respondida, marque sua resposta como a resposta do post. É isso.

Comment: ah sim, mas eu só consigo marcar minha própria resposta após 2 dias... aaprece a mensagem **você só pode aceitar sua própria resposta em 2 dias**

Answer (score 2):

Os tipos de dados `decimal` são salvos no banco de dados com o formato, i.e., `########.##`, portanto, a *string* do exemplo no formato **R$ 1.300.000,00** tem que ser passada para o banco de dados com o formato **1300000.00**.

Como já foi falado você poderia usar o JavaScript para isso, mas não há garantia de segurança aí.

Usando o C# você poderia facilmente implementar um método para substituir todos os caracteres não numéricos da `string` e convertê-la finalmente em `decimal`:

```js
public decimal Salario
{
    get { return _salario; }
    set { _salario = value.Replace("R$ ", string.Empty).Replace(".", string.Empty).Replace(",", "."); }
}
```

Esse é só um exemplo. Você poderia usar diversas funções para tratar a `string`.

A Microsoft recomenda o uso de [.tryParse()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9zbda557(v=vs.110).aspx).

Você ainda poderia usar

```js
var _salario = string.Join("", _salario.Where(char.IsDigit));

_salario = _salario/100;
```

O exemplo acima junta tudo que for caracter numérico em uma única `string`, por isso tem que dividir por `100`, já que `R$ 1.300.000,00` retornaria `130000000`.

Comment: Obrigado @StillBuggin mas acabei resolvendo de outra forma. vou postar aqui como resolvi. Valeu